# LoadError using approximate bayesian criteria

Tags: optimization, julia, differential-equations

I am getting an error that is confusing me.

```
using DifferentialEquations
using RecursiveArrayTools # for VectorOfArray
using DiffEqBayes
f2 = @ode_def_nohes LotkaVolterraTest begin
  dx = x*(1 - x - A*y)
  dy = rho*y*(1 - B*x - y)
end A B rho

u0 = [1.0;1.0]
tspan = (0.0,10.0)
p = [0.2,0.5,0.3]
prob = ODEProblem(f2,u0,tspan,p)
sol = solve(prob,Tsit5())
t = collect(linspace(0,10,200))
randomized = VectorOfArray([(sol(t[i]) + .01randn(2)) for i in 1:length(t)])
data = convert(Array,randomized)

priors = [Uniform(0.0, 2.0), Uniform(0.0, 2.0), Uniform(0.0, 2.0)]
bayesian_result_abc = abc_inference(prob, Tsit5(), t, data,
priors;num_samples=500)
```

Returns the error

```
ERROR: LoadError: DimensionMismatch("first array has length 400 which does not match the length of the second, 398.")
while loading..., in expression starting on line 20.
```

I have not been able to locate any array of size 400 or 398.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: For reference, the solution builds a 2x200 array but due to a bug it's not saving the starting time, so it's a 2x199 array. Those are the 400 and 398.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I was going crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DiffEqBayes.jl/issues/52, that was due to an error in passing the `t`. This has been fixed on master so you can use that or wait some time, we will have a new release soon with the 1.0 upgrades which will have this fixed too.

Thanks!

Comment: I'll just release this right now and fix the issue. `Pkg.update()` in about half an hour.